# Apache Commons FileUpload problem on Glassfish server

Tags: java, file-upload, glassfish, apache-commons-fileupload

I have simple web app that just has one Servlet that accepts data file and saves it to the server. I'm using "[apache commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)" library. File uploading work fine on my local server (I'm using Glassfish for my Dev and Prod server). I can upload any size files. Here is my memory info:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Here is the code for my servlet:

```
...
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("Let's try to do something with your request");
    getMultipartRequestFile(request);
}

// Handling uploaded file with commons-fileupload library
private void getMultipartRequestFile(HttpServletRequest request){

    if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))          // if not is multi part then exit this function
        return;

    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();        // Create a factory for file items
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  // Create a new file upload handler

    //Create a progress listener
    ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener(){
        private long megaBytes = -1;
           public void update(long pBytesRead, long pContentLength, int pItems) {
               long mBytes = pBytesRead / 1000000;
               if (megaBytes == mBytes) {
                   return;
               }
               megaBytes = mBytes;
               if (pContentLength == -1) {
                   log.info("So far, " + dec.format(pBytesRead/1024.0/1024.0) + " have been read.");
               } else {
                   log.info("So far, " + dec.format(pBytesRead/1024.0/1024.0) + "\tof " + dec.format(pContentLength/1024.0/1024.0));
               }
           }
    };
    upload.setProgressListener(progressListener);

    // Parse the request
    try {
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        // Process the uploaded items
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (item.isFormField()) {
                processFormField(item);
            } else {
                processUploadedFile(item);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// this is where all magic with the file will happen
private void processUploadedFile(FileItem item){

    if (!item.isFormField()) {

        String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
        String fileName = item.getName();
        String contentType = item.getContentType();
        boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();

        log.info("Field name: " + fieldName + "\nFile Name: " + fileName + "\nContent type: " +contentType+ "\nSize: " + dec.format(sizeInBytes/1024.0/1024.0));

        // write uploaded file to hdd
        File uploadedFile = new File(FILES_FOLDER + fileName);  

        try {
            item.write(uploadedFile);           
            log.info("File location: " + FILES_FOLDER + fileName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warning("File cannot be writtet to the disc");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
...
```

And this is output with Error:

```
[#|2009-07-13T22:19:31.822+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|Let's try to do something with 
your request|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:31.823+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 0.00 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:33.403+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 0.95 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:34.109+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 1.91 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:34.739+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 2.86 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:35.371+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 3.82 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:35.989+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;|So far, 4.77 mb  of 87.64 mb|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:36.938+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0;_RequestID=99b72ec5-047c-4a86-9160-994ea31848a2;|org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
        at com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader.getMultipartRequestFile(Fileuploader.java:109)
        at com.athena.video.upload.server.Fileuploader.doPost(Fileuploader.java:47)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:983)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:85)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
        ... 33 more
|#]

[#|2009-07-13T22:19:37.839+0000|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;_RequestID=528b60b2-7083-4f27-a1de-0c90df2a34f1;|WEB0777: Unblocking keep-alive exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC4662: Request header is too large
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:740)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:442)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.parseRequest(DefaultProcessorTask.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:577)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
```

Here is what I also tried to add to my domain.xml:

```
<http-listener acceptor-threads="1" address="0.0.0.0" blocking-enabled="false" default-virtual-server="server" enabled="true" family="inet" id="http-listener-1" port="8080" security-enabled="false" server-name="" xpowered-by="true">
          <property name="maxPostSize" value="0"/> <!-- 0 means no max -->
          <property name="proxiedProtocols" value="ws/tcp"/>
</http-listener>
```

Any idea why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of the glassfish server on the both. I had the same issue and figured out that apache commons file upload has issues on glassfish server 3.1.2. When i upgraded to server version 3.1.2.2 (build 5), the file upload functionality works fine.

Please refer the following issue http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue but I'm using glassfish server 3.1.2.2 and librairies from lib/install (commons-io-1.3.1 and commons-fileupload-1.1.1) :(

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC4662: Request header is too large
```

You need to configure the HTTP connector to use a larger buffer.

There should be a parameter "maxPostSize" in the settings of the HTTP listener.

Comment: Nope, did not work. Here is what I have in my domain.xml file:
<http-listener acceptor-threads="1" address="0.0.0.0" blocking-enabled="false" default-virtual-server="server" enabled="true" family="inet" id="http-listener-1" port="8080" security-enabled="false" server-name="" xpowered-by="true">
          <property name="maxPostSize" value="0"/> <!-- 0 means no max -->
          <property name="proxiedProtocols" value="ws/tcp"/>
        </http-listener>

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate. Do you use the same version of the library/container on both servers? Could you sniff your file upload (using an apache tool - can't remember the name) and check if it gets uploaded properly? You could manually grab the uploaded body in the servlet and check if there is no corruption from a servlet filter/default request parser?

I also found a this [issue here](http://www.mail-archive.com/struts-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg96469.html). Basically it states that socket timeout during the upload caused the exception.